# Was Rem's warning fake?

Tags: death-note

Rem warned Light not to hurt Misa or it would kill Light by writing his name in it's Deathnote, but Ryuk had mentioned in the last episode as well as before that either Ryuk would kill Light or that Light would die after living his natural lifespan. As Ryuk has to kill him, was Rem's warning a bluff?

If so, couldn't Light, being a genius, see through his bluff??

Comment: I could have sworn Ryuk said that he would write Light's name down in the Death Note when he is at his end - to prevent Light from going to heaven. I think Ryuk was trying to iterate the point that Light's death will be by Death Note, whether it is by himself or any other shinigami.

Comment: Just based on REM killing L, isn't it obvious she could've killed Light/Kira as well? Both L and Kira were humans... REM a shinigami...

Answer (score 11):

Rem warned Light, but later Misa told Rem not to harm him, that she would rather die first. So Rem, in order to preserve Misa's happiness,couldn't kill him.

Light, being a genius, learned how to take advantage of the situation, and used Rem on his plans, manipulating her like any other.

Comment: but initially Rem did threaten Light.. so was Rem bluffing at that point of time?

Comment: @Adeetya It wasn't a bluff. If Light was going to get Misa killed, Rem would have killed Light. That is why Light needed to keep Misa alive and thus created the great plan where L would write down Misa's name in the note. Rem was then forced to kill L and sacrifice her own life.

Comment: @Adeetya When Rem warned Light, she meant it. Then, Light outsmarted her. Anyway, as krikara pointed, Light never tried to kill Misa, so Rem never had the occasion to prove her threats.

Answer (score 6):

## Chapter 30

Rem threatens Light by saying

> If you try to harm this girl, I will write your name in my note and kill you.

[image]

## Chapter 57

Six months after Rem threatens Light, the killing spree has begun again as soon as Misa was released. Because of this L assumes correctly that Misa is the second killer. Rem knows that if she doesn't take action Misa will be killed soon and she also realizes that this is exactly what Light had planned. Therefore she considers killing Light as she had stated six months earlier, but by now she realizes she can't kill him. Her statement wasn't a bluff, she just realizes that there would be no point on killing Light. On the contrary, and I quote:

> With this, killing Yagami Light means nothing. Misa cannot be saved.. More than that, Misa will be lost as an ally and I will be driven more quickly into a corner... No. I already know that if Yagami Light dies, then Misa will lose all will to live. Yagami Light is already a human who is in many ways, necessary for Misa to continue living...

[image]

Rem had played her cards well, but Light played better. He had completely manipulated the situation, resulting in the death of a Death God. If Rem wanted to save Misa, she had to kill L and had to do so quickly. As much as she might have hated Light, killing him would result in the complete opposite of what she wanted and would make her death an utterly useless sacrifice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule in How To Read 13 that states "Only a God of Death that has passed on their Death Note to a human is able to kill the owner of the Death Note."  This means that Rem could only kill Light if he was the owner her second Death Note. It was either a bluff or a mistake.            [Rule 34 item 3](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXXIV):

> Only a god of death that has passed on their Death Note to a human is able to kill the owner of the Death Note.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing no one answered what is clear to my eyes and is so simple, the answer is so simple though no one here noticed ><

When you follow the events in the anime/manga, this isn't really a question:

1 - Rem **gives** Misa Geluss's Death Note.

2 - When Misa meeting Light, she's handing Light her Death Note - from now on **Rem's Death Note is in Light's hands**, Misa never get her Death Note back before being confined by L.

[image]

3 - While being confined by L, Misa is forfeiting her Death Note that Light's holds at the moment, making Light **the owner of the notebook**.

[image]

4 - **Light is giving Rem's notebook** to give it to Ryuk and then burry it for Misa, because that notebook was in use by Misa, so after Light's memories back she would touch that Death Note and *her memories will return*.

[image]

5 - After Higuchi's death, Light telling her to go dig the buried Death Note so her memories will return. **Only now her original Death Note returns to her possession**.

[image]

Let's now review the threat from Rem to Light:

In ep14 when Light threaten Misa he will kill him she's telling him - "I won't let you do it Yagami Light, *If you will kill this girl I will write your name in the notebook and kill you.* I can see her lifespan. If she'll be killed before her end I will think that you are the killer."

Now, as other specified there's this rule:

> How to use XXXIV
>
> 1. The owner of the Death Note cannot be killed by a god of death who is living in the world of the gods of death.
> 2. Also, a god of death who comes to the human world, in the objective to kill the owner of the Death Note, will not be able to do
>    so.
> 3. Only a god of death that has passed on their Death Note to a human is able to kill the owner of the Death Note.

From the look of the rule, the rules doesn't apply to other human but to other shinigami that cannot kill, [check this Q&A](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/is-ryuk-the-only-one-who-can-kill-light) that [kaine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/3561/kaine) proved that other human *can* kill other Death Note holder though other shinigami cannot kill them.

What that has to do with here? Well, as I explained Misa borrowed Light the Death Note that Rem *gave* to her, Rem clearly specified that if she'll be dead before her lifespan will be over - she'll kill Light, **as Light is now the holder of the Death Note he will be the owner of it after killing Misa** and since the Death Note used to be Rem's notebook she'll have the same power as Ryuk has to kill him since she passed the Death Note to Missa, though Rem didn't gave it to Light since Missa only borrowed it to him it's still considered Rem's old Death Note and to her to kill him. So the answer is clear **that her threat was real** and the things really simple and clear.

Though you could go and say it isn't true since in the end Rem hasn't gave it to him, though to be foolish claim, the evidence for that is the need for Light **to give Rem the Death Note when forfeiting it** because she also needs to follow Light for using the Death Note, her former ownership of the Death Note didn't stopped when Missa borrowed it to Light 'till he forfeited it.

As for other places as mentioned in this Q&A, Rem could kill Light after he killed higuchi since Rem gave Higuchi Ryuk's former Death Note since **she's the shinigami of that Death Note now**, now Light is again own Rem's Death Note she's able to kill him since he gained ownership of the notebook after holding it while killing Higuchi so Light considered the ownership of that notebook.

Answer (score 0):

In [How to Read XXXIV](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_XXXIV), the third point reads,

> Only a god of death that has passed on their Death Note to a human is
>   able to kill the owner of the Death Note.

that means ryuk is the only on who could killed light yagami

Comment: Where did you get that bolded line from, either way this is false as if it was true Light would have been unable to kill Kyosuke Higuchi in *Episode 23 - Frenzy* who was the owner of Ryuk's Death Note at the time (in which Light held onto it untill Kyosuke died to become the next owner)

Comment: it's a rule of the death note.

Comment: Ahhh, i found it, How to Read XXXIV, the rule would seem to cover only interaction between Shinigami so my earlier evidence is incorrect, however remember that Light's Death Note is not Ryuk's but Sidoh's which was stolen so it was never "pass on" to Light

Comment: but that would mean, ryuk shouldn't have been able to kill light -.-

Comment: i retract my previous comments, according to [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11602/1587) and [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11603/1587) while the Death Note Light was using at the time Rem threatened him was actually Sidoh's, Ryuk had claimed ownership by tricking the Shinigami King, so the remaining question is if Ryuk had technically passed it onto Light, if so, at that time **Rem can't kill Light**

Comment: It says that an owner of the Death Note can only be killed by a god of death who has passed on their Death Note to a human. Rem took ownership of Gelus's Death Note and passed it onto Misa, which meets the criteria presented in that rule. It doesn't specifically say that the god of death can only kill the human who received _their_ Death Note.