# How did Ryuk trick the King of Death Gods?

Tags: death-note

In chapter 27, Misa says

> Ryuuku tricked the king of the gods of death to get the second death note that kira is using.

Does anybody know how Ryuk tricked the king of Gods and got his Death Note?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it written further in the story? Have you read all of it yet?

Comment: If i remember in the anime Rem is mistaken as is assuming Ryuk tricked the Shinigami King, Ryuk's second death note actually came from Sidoh, however i don't know if this was adapted from the manga

Comment: @Memor-X It was. In the manga, the Death Note Light was using was also Sidoh's. That's why I wondered how he tricked the King of Gods. Whether it would be related to Sidoh's DN, or whether he would even have had a third DN or whether Rem was indeed just mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Ryuk tricked the king of Gods by pretending he had lost his Death Note.

## Chapter 60

Sidoh appears for the first time. Sidoh says that he thinks it is about time to kill a human or two. This happens in 2009, 6 years after Ryuk had dropped his/Sidoh's Death Note on earth. From this we can see that Sidoh is a lazy and clumsy Death God, who did not realize he was missing his Death Note for at least 6 years. Which explains how Ryuk became the owner of this Death note. According to [How to Use: XII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_XII), you lose ownership when the Death Note is stolen, unless it is retrieved within 490 days, which it wasn't.

> If you lose the Death Note or have it stolen, you will lose its ownership unless you retrieve it within 490 days.

[image: 60]

## Chapter 65

Sidoh appears again. This time he realized he had lost his Death Note and had asked the King of Gods, whether he had seen his Death Note. At which the King replies that Ryuk had already taken that Death Note, pretending it to be his.

> When I told the King of Kings what it looked like, he said, "Oh Ryuuk said it was the one he'd lost, and took it with him"

[image: 65]

## Conclusion

Ryuk was bored and didn't feel alive in the Death God world. But according to [How to Use: XXIV](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_XXIV), Death Gods are not allowed to stay in the human world for long periods of time. Therefore when Ryuk found Sidoh's Death Note, he saw a once in a lifetime opportunity to have some fun. He pretended to the Death God that the Death Note was his, so he could obtain ownership after 490 days and at that time the story starts.

> The god of death must not stay in the human world without a particular reason. Conditions to stay in the human world are as follows:
>
> - When the god of death’s Death Note is handed to a human.

Comment: I see, the Shinigami King must have found Sidoh's Death Note and held onto it not knowing who's it was, Ryuk tricked the Shinigami King by saying it was his, this way Rem is not mistaken that Ryuk tricked the Shinigami King in getting a second book while still keeping to the fact it was Sidoh's

Comment: @Memor-X I originally put that part about the king finding the note in the answer too, but to be honest, in the anime the deathgod king only says "that was the notebook ryuk dropped", from which this isn't as obvious. So I left it out, because I wasn't 100% sure, but it must have been something like that.

Comment: Actully i don't think the [Shinigami King](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Shinigami_King) is ever shown in the anime, i think the comment you refer to was from [Armonia Justin Beyondormason](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Armonia_Justin_Beyondormason)

Comment: @Memor-X I mean, the exact same scene in the anime. I double checked to check for mistranslations for what Sidoh said and in the manga he says what you can see in the answer, which clearly points at Ryuk pretending to be looking for his lost notebook, while in the anime Sidoh says in episode 28 "And when I told him what it looked like, he told me that was the notebook Ryuk dropped". While here it might have been the king asking why ryuk was going to earth. He could have pretended that he had dropped his notebook by accident and needed to retrieve it or something. That's why I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure he pretended to have lost his Death Note and got  a new one off the king. However, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Would that mean, he had 3 notes at the beginning of the story?

Comment: Possibly. He may have known Sidoh would come to get it back so got a backup one for when he did, or deliberately lured Sidoh there to make things more interesting.

Comment: Do you think there would be any proof to this in the manga?

Comment: Probably not. It's just a speculation of mine but it seems like something he would do.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is another theory, Ryuk might be the shinigami king himself therefore as access to infinite number of notes, since the shinigami world is in ruins there isn't any actual proof that it has any particular authority structure, the shinigami sidoh talked to might have pretended to be the king of the death gods to protect ryuk's identity, and since we never saw the king of the shinigami in the manga it might have being ryuk all along, also the bag ryuk is keeping is death note has a strange design and we never saw another shinigami in the manga keeping is death note in a bag, which means ryuk might have a sort of bag to keep his death note because he is the actual king.

Comment: This is incorrect as the King of Death (Shinigami King) does make an appearance, and as we can see in his [wikia page](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Shinigami_King) he doesn't look a thing like Ryuk