# Why was Ryuk tied to Light's Death Note?

Tags: death-note

In [How to Use: XIII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_XIII), in the second point it says

> The god of Death always remains with the owner of the Death Note.

indicating that a Shinigami will remain with the owner of their Death Note, Light learns this and gathers a group of friends to try and hide himself with Ryuk following him when Misa is trying to find him (she finds him because of her Eyes)

However, the Death Note Light had in the beginning isn't Ryuk's but Sidoh's which Ryuk stole, and unlike Gelus who died and Rem probably obtained ownership of Gelus's Death Note afterwards, Sidoh was still alive so even if Light became the owner after Ryuk dropped it in the human world, the Shinigami who was supposed to be with like was Sidoh.

Also in [How to Use 2](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_II), the second point says

> The owner of the note can recognize the image and voice of the original owner, i.e. a god of death.

So is there an explanation as to how Ryuk was tied with Light's Death Note having stolen it from Sidoh?

Comment: Ryuk wasn't tied to Light. He was just bored and what would the point be of throwing a DN on earth if you aren't going to enjoy it.

Comment: @PeterRaeves i wasn't talking about Light but the Death Note Light used originally which is Sidoh's, in a sense i'm asking why Sidoh didn't show up instead of Ryuk

Comment: That doesn't change my comment. Ryuk is only tied to the DN around his waist, so he can go wherever he pleases. He steals Sidoh's DN and throws it on earth to have some fun. So he isn't tied to that DN at all, which you can see, since he only arrives on earth after 5 days. He could leave at anytime, he just doesn't do so, to have some fun with Light.

Comment: @PeterRaeves also, at least in the anime Ryuk points out he can't leave Light's side which would give Misa a hint who was Kira if she herself had a Shinigami (as i point out in the second paragraph)

Comment: He lied... He was pretending it was his own DN.

Comment: Okay sorry... After rereading the whole conversation between Ryuk and Sidoh, I was wrong. He wasn't lying after all. Ryuk was tied to the DN, because he was the real owner at that time (Light wouldn't be able to see him if he wasn't of course, silly me), which he mentions in chapter 66. If I find out how ownership was transferred to Ryuk from Sidoh in the first place, I'll try to answer this question. This will then probably become related to this question http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/how-did-ryuk-trick-the-king-of-death-gods

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [How to use II](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_II):

> The owner of the note can recognize the image and voice of the original owner, i.e. a god of death.

Therefore the only explanation for Light being able to see Ryuk would be, that **Ryuk is the original owner**. But how did Ryuk become the owner of Sidoh's Death Note? As I explained at [How did Ryuk trick the King of Death Gods?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/how-did-ryuk-trick-the-king-of-death-gods/11602#11602), it is because of [How to Use XII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use%3a_XII):

> If you lose the Death Note or have it stolen, you will lose its ownership unless you retrieve it within 490 days.

Ryuk became owner of Sidoh's Death Note because of this rule. It wasn't until chapter 65 that Sidoh realized that he had lost his Death Note, which is 6 years after Ryuk first dropped the Death Note down to earth. If it took him at least 6 years to realize he had lost his Death Note, it would be safe to assume that Ryuk had already found the Death Note 490 days before he dropped it down to earth, claiming ownership and becoming tied to that particular Death Note.

Comment: Ahhh, so point 1 in How to Use XII applies to Shinigami aswell, i've always assumed that when that if a rule applied to Shinigami it would indicate that

Comment: Well I'm not Ohba-san, but most of the usage rules go for both, so unless specified otherwise I assume they do.

Answer (score -1):

Actually a shinigami or god of death is mortal(rem,the shinigami attach with miss and one more shinigami died)..to increase their age,they used to steal age from the human world So here Ryuk the most brilliant shinigami tricked light from the beginning.he actually steal the light life. This is the most interesting theory I come up with.

So my theory is:

1. if shinigami write a person death ,he also convert into the sand.so they only can reduce life of a human but can’t kill.(rem told to miss how shinigami use their more book)
2. to kill a person by shinigami ,by writing name is only possible when human life span is completely finish.in that case shinigami will not die. Also as shinigami can see a person life span so it’s easy for them also.(at the end ryuk named lighat name in his death note) and he did not died
3. many more

Comment: Hi. If you are going to write an opinion or speculation, support it with facts. As it stands, your answer is mostly supported by assumptions only. Cite sources/references from the manga/anime that made you come up with your theory. If you're unsure of your answer, revise it first before posting. Thanks! :)