# Is Ryuk the only one who can kill Light?

Tags: death-note

> Only a god of death that has passed on their Death Note to a human is
>   able to kill the owner of the Death Note**

This confuses me, because Light was able to kill Jack Neylon and Higuchi (although he wrote Higuchi's name on a paper from his notebook, so that maybe explains how he could have killed him). So, what does this rule exactly mean? Does this rule mean that if I write Light Yagami's name in a Death Note, he wouldn't die, since only Ryuk can kill him?

Comment: Where did you see this rule? Can you show reference. I don't remember such a rule though its possible I gave up my notebook and forgot. Worth noting it could be the active owner of the Death Note can only be killed by the shinigami, also worth noting owners of deathnote can kill themselves by writing their names into the notebook)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to use XXXIV

1. The owner of the Death Note cannot be killed by a god of death who is living in the world of the gods of death.
2. Also, a god of death who comes to the human world, in the objective to kill the owner of the Death Note, will not be able to do so.
3. Only a god of death that has passed on their Death Note to a human is able to kill the owner of the Death Note.

As the rules are grouped together, it seems they are related.  In context, they imply that gods of death cannot kill Death Note owners with the exception of the original owner. Keep in mind that the rules seem to be a collection of observations; not the "programming language" of the Death Note.  This means some wording may not be perfect. In practice, Light was able to kill Death Note owners whose original owners were not shown to also write down their names.

Also, note that everyone already has an expiration date so they are never immortal from non-Death Note related deaths.

That being said, that interpretation sounds as if an owner who found Misa's old notebook after the Shinigami was dead would effectively be immortal or at least immune to all Death Note users.  This seems unlikely.

Comment: So that means Ryuk isn't the only one who can kill Light? @kaine

Comment: I believe Light could die of any normal cause or  his name being written by a human. Ryuk, however, promised that before his lifespan ended, he would write Lights name in his book. So for almost any cause of death, he would actually die of a heart attack as Ryuk wrote his name down rather than let him die normally.

Comment: So in the end Ryuk is really the only who kills Light.

Comment: He would have likely died of blood loss/bullet wounds anyways. But yes, Ryuk killed Light with a heart attack before he could die of anything else and knew he was about to die very soon but didnt warn him.

Comment: He wouldn't have died of bloot loss. Ryuk said, he didn't want to wait till Light dies in prison.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I forgot that line.  I guess that means someone would have caught him and gave him medical treatment before he died.  Still means he could have died from whatever the cause of death in the prison would be though.

Comment: I could remember that line because it's the last thing Ryuk says to my favorite character. Also i think Light would have died when his lifespan ended.

Comment: Wait you like Light, Dark? I wouldnt have guessed! Now I remember it the scene was amazing; I need to rewatch it.

Comment: Lol. Yeah Light was my favorite character in Death Note. Even i don't like to see him die, his death scene was amazing.